# trouble returning json from python to javascript with ajax

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, flask

I'm sending `articleUrl` from my .js to my python function, which works fine. I then want my python function to return `pubscore` back to the .js.

pubscore prints fine in the .py, but then I get **"Uncaught ReferenceError: pubscore is not defined at Object.myFunction [as success] (background.js:41)"**. Line 41 is `var myPubscore = pubscore` in the .js.

**background.js**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: `${url}/buttoncolor`,
    data: articleUrl,
    success: function urlFunction(data) {
    var myPubscore = pubscore;
    console.log(myPubscore);
    }
})
```

**application.py**

```
def buttoncolor():
    import json
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not request.form['url']:
            flash('Please enter all the fields', 'error')
        else:
            rurl = request.form['url']

            ...

            pubscore = pub_tuple[8]
            print(pubscore)
            return json.dumps(pubscore)
    else:
        strscore = str(pubscore)
        message = {'greeting': strscore}
        return jsonify(message)  # serialize and use JSON headers
```

**Suggested code that didn't work for me but could be helpful to someone else**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.type == "articleUrl") {
        var articleUrl = request;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: `${url}/buttoncolor`,
            data: articleUrl,
            success: function(){ alert('success');
            }
        })

        $.getJSON(`${url}/buttoncolor`,{data: articleUrl}, function(data) {
        doWork(data.greetings);
        });

        function doWork(myPubscore){
        console.log(myPubscore);
        if (myPubscore > 1)
        {console.log("myPubscore is more than 1")}
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```js
function doWork(data) {
  const myPubscore = data.greeting;
  console.log(myPubscore)
  if (myPubscore > 1) {
    console.log("myPubscore is more than 1")
  }
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.type == "articleUrl") {
    var articleUrl = request;
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: `${url}/buttoncolor`,
      data: articleUrl,
      success: doWork,
      error: function(e) {
        console.log("error", e)
      }
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, that got me farther — I'm not getting the error message anymore. But myPubscore prints as "undefined". I tried adding JSON.parse(myPubscore); but then I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0"

Comment: Thanks. Having a bit of trouble figuring out where to put that new line — does that go inside the success function, go in the doWork function, or is it separate altogether? (Does it replace one of the other functions?) I tried it as a separate function but got "500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)"

Comment: Hmm, still getting the "500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)". I'm pasting the updated code including the context in case I'm missing something.

Comment: Thanks. I do need the AJAX to send the articleUrl from my .js to my .py in the first place ... I'm having trouble with the second half of the AJAX, which is sending pubscore from the .py to the .js

Comment: I'm confused — I'm not trying to get data: articleUrl from my .py, I'm trying to get pubscore.

I'm trying to: 1. Post articleUrl from js to py and 2. Get pubscore from py to js.

Comment: I just don't understand why the get also uses {data: articleUrl} or why the posts involves doWork

Comment: In my function, I try to get "pubscore" not "articleUrl". My post function does not involve the doWork function.

Comment: But you SEND the articleurl to the server to get the pub score according to your original code

Comment: When I just try the $.post jquery, I get "500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)" in my js and "400 Bad Request:" at "if not request.form['url']:" in my py

Comment: Why would the post work fine with my ajax but not with your jquery?

Comment: Ok, I changed the code. Please try the above which is your original post with the changed success and an added error handler